# Update OpenShift deployment based on GitLab webhook

Tags: gitlab, openshift, openshift-origin

I am storing my images on GitLab, and I want that whenever a new image is created, the OpenShift deployment to be updated, is this possible directly from a OpenShift functionality?

Answer (score 0):

ArgoCD and the ArgoCD operator should be able to do that, and more:

Ref:

- https://demo.openshift.com/en/latest/argocd/
- https://argocd-operator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/openshift/